# If $f \circ f$ continuous prove $f$ continuous

Tags: continuity, monotone-functions

> Let $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ strictly increasing so that
>   $f \circ f$ is continuous. Prove $f$ is continuous.

I can prove this using sequences, but it's quite tedious.

**My question is: Does anyone know how to prove this using some kind of more general result (a theorem or something)?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A strictly increasing function $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ is continuous if and only if it has no jump discontinuity, which is the case if and only if $f[\Bbb R]$ is order-convex. Thus, if $f$ is not continuous, there are $a,b,c,d\in\Bbb R$ such that $a\le b<c\le d$, $(c,d)\cap f[\Bbb R]=\varnothing$, and $a,d\in f[\Bbb R]$. Let $u,v\in\Bbb R$ be such that $f(u)=a$ and $f(v)=d$. Then

$$(f\circ f)\big[[u,v]\big]=f\big[[a,d]\big]$$

is not convex. Since $f\circ f$ is strictly increasing, $(f\circ f)[\Bbb R]$ is not convex, and hence $f\circ f$ is not continuous.

Comment: Although both are technically correct, I would say "connected" instead of "convex" in $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Nice proof, but where is the more general result?

Comment: @Greg: I prefer *convex* (or *order-convex*): it’s more immediately descriptive, and it better fits the context established by *monotone*. But of course it’s largely a matter of taste.

Comment: @Eugen: The more general result is stated in the first sentence. I doubt that you’ll find anything much more general than that: the setting is a pretty specialized one to begin with.

Comment: I also used this in my proof, that's why I expected something else, a more general condition for $f$ to be continuous when $f \circ f$ is continuous, so that the strictly increasing condition appears as a particular case.

Comment: @Eugen: I don’t offhand know of anything like that. I suspect that if there is an applicable result that is substantially more general, the work done in showing that a strictly increasing function satisfies the hypothesis of the result is on a par with (and quite possibly very similar to) the work done in showing the result here directly. (I was primarily trying to get a simple argument that avoided the use of sequences and multiple cases.)