# Continuity of the function $f$, if $f\circ f + f$ is continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let us define function $f$,
$$f:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$$

I know that continuity of $f\circ f$ does not imply continuity of $f
$ (for instance, Dirichlet's function).

Can we say anything about the continuity of $f$ if $f\circ f + f$ is continuous?

[If $f \circ f$ continuous prove $f$ continuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1805947/if-f-circ-f-continuous-prove-f-continuous) shows that continuity of $f\circ f$ implies continuity of $f$, provided $f$ is strictly increasing function.

Is there any other extra condition like strictly monotonic property or restricting domain which needs to be supplied to make given function $f$ continuous if $f\circ f + f$ is continuous?

Answer (score 4):

Consider a function like $f(x) = 1,\ \text{if}\ x<0$, $f(x)=0, \text{if}\ x=0$ and $f(x)=-1$ if $x>0$. Then $f\circ f+f = 0$ identically but $f$ is not continuous.

Comment: And since this example is monotonic its clear any easy condition wouldn't work to make $f$ continuous

Comment: What about strictly increasing, as asked by the OP?

Comment: @MrFlaze Thanks for the example. Did you try for strictly increasing case and if not possible then for restricting domain? Can you prove it for $[a, b]$?

Comment: I think its a bit difficult for the strictly increasing case. As for restricting the domain, notice that this same example will work by moving the origin of the graph to $(a+b)/2$..

Comment: @MrFlaze Can we use some other restriction to make this problem simple enough to show the continuity of $f$?

Comment: @MrFlaze But function $f\circ f + f$ is not continuous.

Comment: Hmm, it seems very tricky to do the strictly monotone case; just curious whether this question is from a text or something you made up?